# How to call a FORM VIEW via a button? (Odoo 13 Enterprise)

Tags: button, odoo, formview

I defined a button via "Server Actions" in this FORM VIEW:
[image]

And created another FORM VIEW from the submenu.
[image]

Then I'd tried to call this FORM VIEW via the button, but it's not worked.

So how to call this FORM VIEW via the button?

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: Question: You have created action for that form view and linked to this button right but it's not working?

Comment: I define a button via server actions and created an action to call FORM VIEW but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give

```
"view_mode" : "form"
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. But I still got the same error after using your code

Answer (score 0):

in xml :

```xml
<record id="account_common_report_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Common Report</field>
    <field name="model">account.common.report</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Report Options">
        <group col="4">
            <header>
                <button name="check_report" string="Print" type="object" 
                       default_focus="1" class="oe_highlight"/>
                <button string="Cancel" class="btn btn-secondary" />
            </header>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

python :
call every things call

```python
def check_report(self):

    self.ensure_one()
    data = {}
    data['ids'] = self.env.context.get('active_ids', [])
    data['model'] = self.env.context.get('active_model', 'ir.ui.menu')
    data['form'] = self.read(['date_from', 'date_to', 'journal_ids', 'target_move', 'company_id'])[0]
    used_context = self._build_contexts(data)
    data['form']['used_context'] = dict(used_context, lang=get_lang(self.env).code)
    return self.with_context(discard_logo_check=True)._print_report(data)
```